# Что делать при ошибке в компиляции киви приложения на линуксе

Tags: python, linux

shutil.Error: [('/mnt/c/Compil_kivy/.buildozer/applibs', '/mnt/c/Compil_kivy/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/c/Compil_kivy/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs'")]

Answer (score 0):

попробуй добавить к команде sudo в начале

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).